# run inline shell script as root

Tags: bash, shell

I have a user, who's a passwordless sudoer. I need to execute shell script file with him, and make him execute one block as sudo. E.g:

```
su root <<"AS_ROOT"
# do something with my linux
AS_ROOT
```

But nothing works. I tried:
`su - root <<...`
`sudo -s -- <<...`

It barks back at me. I'm on ubuntu 16.04 lts.

Thank you.

Comment: barks back what?

Comment: Btw: `sudo` != `su`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) points out, `su` is a different utility to which `sudo`'s configuration doesn't apply.

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
sudo -s <<'AS_ROOT'
echo "Hi from $USER."
AS_ROOT
```

This should output `Hi from root.`

Note that `-s` is needed to tell `sudo` to create a *shell* in order to interpret the commands passed via stdin (the here-doc). That shell is the current user's default shell, as reflected in environment variable `$SHELL`.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed it. And thank you for the explanation.